# Cannot be provided without an @provides-annotated method for migration from dagger to hilt

Tags: android, factory, dagger, dagger-hilt

Please help me with such error.
I'm trying to use dagger and hilt in one project.

DataSource eas using a dagger, but I want to implement hilt for use.

And hilt shows an error cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method
for DataSource.Factory

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
interface MessageRepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindMessageRepository(repository: MessageRepositoryImpl): MessageRepository
}



@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
@Module
object MessageModule {

    @Provides
    fun dataSourceFactory(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): DataSource.Factory {
        return DataSource.Factory { name: String? ->
            DataSource(
                appContext,
                name
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and my class of datasource

```
public class DataSource {
public interface Factory {
        DataSource create(String name);
    }
    public DataSource(Context context, String name) {
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        this.appConf = new AppConf(context);
    }

}
```